# how to add shadow to svg vector asset android

Tags: android, layout

How to add shadow on SVG vector asset android .I tried app:elevation but it is not working .
I tried app:elevation="10dp" but nothing happens in layout , no shadow . please describe some other ways .

Comment: Once the SVG has been converted to a bitmap, it's easy (...) to add a shadow to it.

Comment: i import vector asset to android studio . then I tried app:elevation but it doesnt work . so any solution ?

Comment: Did you try it on a real device running api 21 or above?

Answer (score 1):

Use one more xml file which has shadow in it, then use that xml in your vector assert for shadow

Comment: Hello Ranjan, could you please show some sample XML on how to do this? It will really help me a lot, thanks

Comment: you can use layer list for that, Here is an example link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531007/android-combine-drawable-and-shape-into-a-single-drawable-programatically/34531902